# including grain data when querying pillar in saltstack managed file

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have a state using `file.managed`, which generates a config file via a jinja for loop from a key in pillar.

My pillar looks like this:

```
configuration:
  server01:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
  server02:
    key03: value03
    key04: value04
```

and the managed file:

```
{% set kv = pillar['configuration']['server01'] %}
{% for key, value in kv.iteritems() %}
{{ key }}:{ value }};
{% endfor %}
```

The way I differentiate between different servers right now in my state file is

```
config:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/config.conf
    - source: salt://files/{{ grains['id'] }}.conf.jinja
    - template: jinja
```

but this is less than ideal, since I have to create an almost identical file for every server.

Is there a way to dynamically replace `server01` with the ID of the actual server, something like

```
{% set kv = pillar['configuration']['{{ grains[id''] }}'] %}
```

The goal is to generally limit the necessary changes only to the corresponding pillar file, when adding a new server, so other suggestions are also welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should use pillar info in your state file.
your state file like bellow :

```
{% if grains['id'] in pillar['configuration'] %}
{% set nodeinfo = pillar['configuration'][grains['id']] %}
config:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/config.conf
    - source: salt://conf.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - defaults :
      nodeinfo: {{nodeinfo}}
{% endif %}
```

then, conf.jinja:

```
{% for key, value in nodeinfo.iteritems() -%}
{{ key }}:{{ value }};
{% endfor -%}
```

i hope that will solve your problem, thanks.

Comment: perfect. does exactly what I was looking for.