# SaltStack: edit yaml file on minion host based on salt pillar data

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

Say the minion host has a default yaml configuration named `myconf.yaml`. What I want to do is to edit parts of those yaml entries using values from a pillar. I can't even begin to think how to do this on Salt. The only think I can think of is to run a custom python script on the host via `cmd.run` and feed it with input via arguments, but this seems overcomplicated.

I want to avoid `file.managed`. I cannot use a template, since the `.yaml` file is big, and can change by external means. I just want to edit a few parameters in it. I suppose a python script could do it but I thought salt could do it without writing s/w

I have found `salt.states.file.serialize` with the `merge_if_exists` option, I will try this and report.

Comment: maybe you can get a better understanding from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509636/including-grain-data-when-querying-pillar-in-saltstack-managed-file) and its answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done for both json and yaml with [file.serialize](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.serialize). Input can be inline on the state or come from a pillar. A short excerpt follows:

state:

```
cassandra_yaml:
  file:
    - serialize
#    - dataset:
#        concurrent_reads: 8
    - dataset_pillar: cassandra_yaml
    - name: /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
    - formatter: yaml
    - merge_if_exists: True
    - require:
      - pkg: cassandra-pkgs
```

pillar:

```
cassandra_yaml:
  concurrent_reads: "8"
```

Answer (score 2):

You want file.serialize with the `merge_if_exists` option.

```
# states/my_app.sls
something_conf_file:
  file.serialize:
    - name:            /etc/my_app.yaml
    - dataset_pillar:  my_app:mergeconf
    - formatter:       yaml
    - merge_if_exists: true

# pillar/my_app.sls
my_app:
  mergeconf:
    options:
      opt3: 100
      opt4: 200
```

On the target, /etc/my_app.yaml might start out looking like this (before the state is applied):

```
# /etc/my_app.yaml
creds:
  user: a
  pass: b
options:
  opt1: 1
  opt2: 2
  opt3: 3
  opt4: 4
```

And would look like this after the state is applied:

```
creds:
  user: a
  pass: b
options:
  opt1: 1
  opt2: 2
  opt3: 100
  opt4: 200
```

As far as I can tell this uses the same algorithm as pillar merges, so e.g. you can merge or partially overwrite dictionaries, but not lists; lists can only be replaced whole.